# Accidantly removed SD card - Card reader not visible anymore

Tags: sd-card, card-reader

I thoughtlessly removed my SD card from the slot of the card reader while the SD card was in use in gparted and the disk-utility. After I put it in again, it was not visible anymore. It is the same situation with another SD card.
I reopened the disk-utility and the complete card reader doesn't appear anymore. I tried to restart the computer but the situation remains the same - The card reader doesn't appear in the disk-utility.
How can I reactivate it?

Comment: Restart did not solve the problem - Restart after 5 min separated from any power source / power cable unplugged did solve problem.

Comment: Delete question or does it have value for other users?

Comment: Please post it as an answer. Remember, it's [perfectly alright to ask and answer your own question.](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the problem could not be solved by a simple reboot, the following procedure was successful: 
Switching off the computer, then removing any power source for 5 min (simply plugging off power supply cord). After reconnecting and booting, the card reader was detected again.